# Django/Dialogflow chatbot, works from my laptop. when i deploy to a server i have to repeat the same sentence before an intent is matched

Tags: dialogflow-es

I have a development setup (Laptop, Django, Dialogflow, Ngrok) When I test my chatbot all is well.

I have a production setup (Ubuntu server hosted by Digital Ocean, Django, Dialogflow, Nginx, gunicorn) When I test dialog flow has troube matching intents. i.e i have to repeat the same sentence a few times until it matches the intent.

Any ideas why this might be?

I have tried pointing dialogflow fullfillment to my development environment and hit it from the production environment however i still have to repeat myself to get a matched intent.

I have tried pointing dialogflow to the production environment and hitting it from the development server and all works as it should.

conversation tested on production server:

Hello Chris from Cemlyn group! What can I do for you? Something map related perhaps?
return a map
Sorry, I dont understand what you want.
return a map
Sorry, I dont understand what you want.
return a map
Chris what map do you want to return?
1
Sorry, I dont understand what you want.
1
Sorry, I dont understand what you want.
1
OK just to confirm, you want me to return 1 for you Chris
return a map
Chris what map do you want to return?
1
Sorry, I dont understand what you want.
1
Sorry, I dont understand what you want.
1
OK just to confirm, you want me to return 1 for you Chris

Conversation tested from development setup:

Hello Chris from Cemlyn group! What can I do for you? Something map related perhaps?
return a map
Chris what map do you want to return?
1
OK just to confirm, you want me to return 1 for you Chris

the webhook looks like this:

```
def webhook(request):
    # build a request object
    req = json.loads(request.body)
    #s = Session.objects.get(pk='')
    #print(s)
    # get action from json
    action = req.get('queryResult').get('action')
    params = req.get('queryResult').get('parameters')
    print('session hitting webhook - '*3)
    print(request.session.session_key)
    for key, value in request.session.items():
        print('{} => {}'.format(key, value))
    print(req)    

    if action == 'issue_a_map':
        if 'Maps' in params:

            if params['Maps']:

                mapid = int((params['Maps'][0]))
                group = (params['ValleyGroups'][0])

                if mapid == 99:
                    fulfillmentText = {'fulfillmentText': 'issue the next map for ' + group + ' from webhook.'}            
                else:

                    fulfillmentText = {'fulfillmentText': 'issue a map from webhook.'}

    elif action == 'return_a_map':
        print('return a map - '*4)
        if 'Maps' in params:
            if params['Maps']:           
                mapid = int(params['Maps'])
                map = CongMap.objects.get(map_no=mapid)
                if map.issued:
                    retuner = params['username']
                    return_map_form(request, mapid, retuner ) 
                    fulfillmentText = {'fulfillmentText': 'OK I will return map ' + str(mapid) + ' for you ' +params['username']}
                else:
                    #reply = prepresponse('name please','admin','welcome_event')
                    fulfillmentText = {'fulfillmentText': 'Hmmm there is a problem, that map isnt issued currently. A map has to be issued before it can be returned.'}
                    ffr=fulfillment_response()
                    fftext= ffr.fulfillment_text(fulfillmentText)
                    params = {'problem': str(map.map_title) +' map hasnt been issued however we are trying to return it.'}
                    fue = ffr.followup_event_input('ProblemEvent', params)        
                    ffm = None
                    ocx = None
                    reply = ffr.main_response(fftext, ffm, ocx, fue)

                    return JsonResponse(reply, safe=False)

            else:
                fulfillmentText = {'fulfillmentText': 'Sorry I need to know the map no or name.'}       
        else:
            fulfillmentText = {'fulfillmentText': 'Sorry I need to know the map no or name.'}

    elif action == 'help_problem':
        fulfillmentText = {'fulfillmentText': 'OK ' +params['username'] +', I will send him an email asking him to help.'}
        send_mail('Territory Problem', '{}. Please can you help {} with this problem'.format(params['problem'], params['username']), 'territorybot@chivers.io', ['tain259@gmail.com'])
    else:
        fulfillmentText = {'fulfillmentText': 'Sorry, I dont understand what you want.'}
    # return response

    return JsonResponse(fulfillmentText, safe=False)
```

Comment: Hi there, please look at this guide [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). So show some code please :)

Comment: Thanks Jan, the webhook code is the same on both setups

Comment: hey Tain, I just did a general review as a community service. someone who knows dialogflow might help you. by posting good questions you increase the likeliness drastically. just be patient for a day or so.

Comment: I have narrowed down the problem to some difference between Django's runserver and Nginx and gunicorn.  If I stop Nginx on my production server and use python3 manage.py runserver myipaddress:80 then all works as it should